# database mysql error of format

Tags: mysql, database, subquery, syntax-error

below  is a sql query, I am trying to execute on Mysql,but a weird error is present. i am attaching a link for  the image of error. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gogp08ei9u4t85f/1.PNG?dl=0

Note: I tried executing the subquery alone. IT WORKS.
    I tried executing  `select curdate()` IT WORKS.

WHen it comes executing this whole as a query IT STUCKS.

I have also used  ' ' for covering curdate() Still NO EFFECT.

```html
select * from taxi where registration_number in (select taxi_registration_number from shift where shift_date = curdate())
```

Comment: Put the query in the question,dont make people multitask

Comment: I guess query is right in the question. Just the image is not present the reason is I can't post image here.  I do not have ten points. Now :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess taxi and shift have different collations. one table has latin1_general_ci and other latin1_swedish_ci . my advice is that all your tables have same collation so you'll have to alter them:

for example to utf8:

```
alter table taxi convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci;
alter table shift convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: @concerned_user glad to be of assistance. :)